# Поддержка браузеров (движки) javascript

Tags: javascript, браузер, кроссбраузерность, v8

На занятиях по JS поручили следующее задание:

найти информацию о том, как делается и запилить во внешний скрипт-файл, цитирую:

> "поддержку браузеров (движков)"*.

Наверное, я как-то неправильно гуглю, потому что ответа на вопрос путем простого поиска не нашла. Поэтому обращаюсь сюда, наверняка кто-то знает, что это и с чем его есть.

Пример записи должен быть следующий:

```
EDGE (V8, Chakra)
```

Ну и по аналогии для самых популярных браузеров.

Надеюсь, кто-то подскажет хотя бы, где об этом почитать или как реализовать такую штуку.

Comment: Возможно имеется в виду поддержка фич, отсутствующих в старых браузерах и старых версиях движков?

Comment: Ну вероятнее всего. Я так поняла, что речь идет о ситуации, когда код в браузере сталкивается со старым движком. И скрипт, который нас попросили написать, должен обеспечить нормальное отображение контента

Comment: Судя по примеру, возможно, вам нужно написать скрипт, который определяет браузер пользователя?

Comment: Хмм, интересная мысль, с этой стороны я не смотрела на вопрос. Но тогда, скорее, это скрипт, который будет определять не только браузер,но и версию движка...Ну и типа корректное отображение контента на выходе

Comment: Вообще рекомендуется определять не браузер, а наличие конкретных фич. То если если протопип Array, к примеру, не поддерживает метод sort, то расширяем его вручную, а остальной код смело использует чтото вроде [].sort()

Comment: Ну это уже немного не то, как я понимаю. Я вижу это как определение поддержки спецификаций. "С точки зрения поддержки в браузерах люди обычно говорят о «совместимости с ECMAScript»" - цитата с одного сайта. от нас походу хотели, чтобы мы прописали  эту самую совместимость для всех браузеров